# If/elif/else loop executing else statement when if is met

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have the following code as part of a function:

```
print("Is the fluid water/steam or R-134a: ")
fluid = input()
if fluid.casefold == "water":
    hin = CP.PropsSI('H','P', pin,"T",lower_temp+zeroC, 'water')
    hout = CP.PropsSI('H','P', pout,"T",upper_temp+zeroC, 'water')
    return
elif fluid.casefold == "r134a" or fluid.casefold == "r-134a":
    hin = CP.PropsSI('H','P', pin,"T",lower_temp+zeroC, 'R134a')
    hout = CP.PropsSI('H','P', pout,"T",upper_temp+zeroC, 'R134a')
    return
else:
    print("Invalid Fluid")
    params()
```

My code always executes the else statement, not the if or elif statements. Am I using casefold incorrectly, or is there some other error that I'm not seeing

Comment: `fluid.casefold()`, it's a method, not a property

Comment: Also, if you never use `fluid` without first calling its `casefold` method, do it once and right away: `fluid = input().casefold()`. And don't, as it appears you are doing, use recursion to implement an infinite loop. Use a `while` loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61860901/if-statement-problem-about-a-small-converter-i-made/61860929?r=SearchResults&s=1|125.5385#61860929

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IF statement problem about a small converter I made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61860901/if-statement-problem-about-a-small-converter-i-made)

Comment: @chepner What would the most appropriate while loop look like?

Comment: Wrap what is shown here in `while True:`; `return` will necessarily exit the loop, so simply omitting the recursive call will cause the loop to repeat in the `else` case.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fuild.casefold()`

```
print("Is the fluid water/steam or R-134a: ")
fluid = input()
if fluid.casefold() == "water":
    hin = CP.PropsSI('H','P', pin,"T",lower_temp+zeroC, 'water')
    hout = CP.PropsSI('H','P', pout,"T",upper_temp+zeroC, 'water')
    return
elif fluid.casefold() == "r134a" or fluid.casefold() == "r-134a":
    hin = CP.PropsSI('H','P', pin,"T",lower_temp+zeroC, 'R134a')
    hout = CP.PropsSI('H','P', pout,"T",upper_temp+zeroC, 'R134a')
    return
else:
    print("Invalid Fluid")
    params()
```